# Crashes on android 4.3 when get calls log by getContentResolver

Tags: android, calllog

I trying to get calls history and group by number, it work well on android 2.3
This is my code:

```
Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(
    CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, new String[] { "number", "name" },
    "number IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY (number", null, "date DESC");
```

But when i run it on android 4.3 (galaxy s3), my project crashes.
This is log:

```
07-28 19:12:32.815: E/AndroidRuntime(25200): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-28 19:12:32.815: E/AndroidRuntime(25200): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "GROUP": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT number, name FROM logs WHERE (logs.logtype=100 OR logs.logtype=110 OR logs.logtype=900 OR logs.logtype=500 OR logs.logtype=800 OR logs.logtype=120 OR logs.logtype=510 OR logs.logtype=1000 OR (logs.logtype=200 AND number NOT IN (SELECT number FROM logs WHERE number LIKE '%@%')) OR logs.logtype=300 OR logs.logtype=950) AND ((number IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY (number) AND ((type != 4)) AND (logtype=100 OR logtype=500 OR logtype=950 OR logtype=1000)) ORDER BY date DESC
07-28 19:12:32.815: E/AndroidRuntime(25200):    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:181)
07-28 19:12:32.815: E/AndroidRuntime(25200):    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:137)
07-28 19:12:32.815: E/AndroidRuntime(25200):    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:385)
07-28 19:12:32.815: E/AndroidRuntime(25200):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:417)
07-28 19:12:32.815: E/AndroidRuntime(25200):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:360)
```

How do i can handle that error ? 
Please help me.

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

It's crashing because you are cheating.

You should not inject GROUP BY (or any other sql query statement) in a content provider query because you cannot assume how the content provider implementation will handle it. This is the reason because the same code works on Android 2.3 and crashes on Android 4.3

Comment: how do i can to do it ? :-(

Comment: Thanks you. I tried handle manually but very slow. I'm trying find a new way to resolve it. :-(